# Terminal output missing

Tags: xorg, xterm

The terminal output often goes missing - the space is there where lines should be but only black background shows. Usually seems to be the first 3-4 lines at the top of the terminal screen, but isn't consistent. Hitting Ctrl-L to refresh the output, sometimes fixes, but often the refresh just misses other lines. Moving the window reliably redraws it.

The problem occurs with both xterm and rxvt, so suggests it's a painting issue rather than the terminal itself.

Running Ubuntu 11.10, but I recall problem appeared (albeit much less often) with 11.04.

X is using the radeon driver with an HIS ATI Radeon HD 5550 PCI express card.

thanks in advance

Comment: In the end I've switched to gnome-terminal which doesn't display the issue. Shame, long live rxvt!

Comment: Hello bee, are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

does the problem also occur with another shell?

You could e.g. open the terminal, then start another shell by typing:

```
sh
```

and then work with this shell. Is the problem reproducible using sh (instead of e.g. bash)?

Greetings from Switzerland, Michael

Comment: Yes - sh, bash, zsh all display the issue